# How to estimate the number of IOs in mysql

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table with fields id and b, and create a non-clustered index b. The tree of index b is 3 levels high. I select * from table where b < 1000 and need to return the table. How to estimate the number of IOs?

I know that traversing the index tree requires 3 times to find index b, and then traverse the primary key index 3 times, a total of 6 times.

Comment: You can't. You don't know anything about what caching is in effect, for example: there might be zero I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 - production system that has been up for a long time.

- If all the necessary blocks are in the buffer_pool, the zero I/O reads are needed.

Case 2 cold system (eg, right after restart) and no blocks are cached.

Case 2.1 -- "3" implies about 1 million rows.  (100 rows per block is a simple Rule of Thumb.)  That implies that only a small percentage of the rows must be looked at, so the INDEX will be used.  (One Data InnoDB Block holds 16kb of data and overhead.  Inddex blocks are similar, but with index info.)

- 3 index BTree blocks reads to find "b=1000".  That contains the `id` value.
- Given that the *all* the necessary columns *anywhere* in the `SELECT` are in the `INDEX` -- 1 read per block 'before' that block.  So, perhaps 1000/100 = 10 block reads.  (This is called "covering index" and is indicated in `EXPLAIN` by "Using Index".)

Case 2.2.  If, on the other hand, `*` includes more than `b` and `id`, and more than, say, 20% of the table is needed, then the INDEX will be ignored, and it will simply read the data's BTree, checking each row for `b<1000`:

- Read all rows of the table -- about 1M/100 = 10K blocks fetched.